# How to inspect Chrome plugin source code?

Tags: plugins, google-chrome

I would like to know how the Chrome plugin "iReader" works. I would like to know what is the magic behind the detect the web page is enable "reader".Moreover, I would like to know how it extract the content of blog post. How can I inspect it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958371/chrome-firefox-access-source-of-an-extension, or you can use the Chrome Developer Console on pages that the extension works on.

Answer (score 0):

Most Chrome plugins are open source so you can download them from the project's homepage. Besides, you can also open the Chrome Developer Tools and switch to script tag. There should be some scripts named "chrome-extension://".

The arbitrary string behind the "chrome-extension://" is the ID of the plugin. If you're using Windows Vista and above, refer to "C:\Users\${YOU USER NAME}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions" to find out the ID of the "iReader".